# Apps Script : write value in widget from server side

Tags: google-apps-script

i would like to create a modal in Apps Script where the user needs to type a number in an input and, when he clicks in "search" button, the text in reference to this number is write in other input.

This is my script (server side) :

```
 function include(filename){
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
 }

 function ajoutLigne() {
   const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const feuille = classeur.getActiveSheet();
   var widget; 
   widget = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("widget.html").evaluate();
   ui.showModalDialog(widget, "Ajout d'une nouvelle ligne");
   widget.setWidth(600);
   widget.setHeight(600);
   }

 function getLibelle(codeArticle){
   const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const feuille = classeur.getSheetByName("BASE ARTICLE");
   var lastRow = feuille.getLastRow();
   var tDonnees = feuille.getRange("B2:C"+lastRow).getValues();
   var nbDonnees = tDonnees.filter(String).length;
   var result = "";
   for (let i = 0; i < nbDonnees; i ++){
     if(tDonnees[i][0] == codeArticle){
       result =  tDonnees[i][1];
     }
   }
   return result;
 }
```

This is my HTML's widget page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <base target="_top">    
     <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
   </head>
   <body>
     <p>Quel code article souhaitez-vous ajouter ?</p><input type="text" id="codeArticle"/>
      
     <input type="button" class="button" value="Recherche" onclick="rechercheLibelle();">

     <p> Libellé correspondant : </p>
     <p id="libelle"></p>

   </body>
 </html>
```

And this is my JavaScript's HTML page :

```
<script>
   function rechercheLibelle(){
      var codeArticle = document.getElementById("codeArticle").value;
      var test = google.script.run.getLibelle(codeArticle);
      console.log(test);
      document.getElementById("libelle").innerHTML = test;    
   }
</script>
```

When i launch in other function getLibelle with a correct value, it's work perfectly. But when i launch rechercheLibelle in the Javascript's HMTL page, i've "undefined" in value for test's variable result.

Anyone can help me with that please. I think the problem comes to "google.script.run.getLibelle(codeArticle)" but i don't know how to translate the result from server side to my widget's html page. Thank you for advance to your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var test = google.script.run.getLibelle(codeArticle);
console.log(test);
document.getElementById("libelle").innerHTML = test;
```

#### To:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(test => {
  console.log(test);
  document.getElementById("libelle").innerHTML = test;
}).getLibelle(codeArticle);
```

- When the script of `getLibelle` at Google Apps Script is finished, the returned value can be retrieved by `withSuccessHandler` at Javascript.

#### Note:

- When I saw your Google Apps Script, `getLibelle` might be able to be modified for reducing the process cost. So, how about the following modification using TextFinder?

  ```
    function getLibelle(codeArticle) {
      const classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const feuille = classeur.getSheetByName("BASE ARTICLE");
      const lastRow = feuille.getLastRow();
      const tDonnees = feuille.getRange("B2:B" + lastRow).createTextFinder(codeArticle).findNext();
      return tDonnees ? tDonnees.offset(0, 1).getValue() : "Value was not found.";
    }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))